# Report prints in Print Preview but only "addnew" records from the first report page

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a MS-Access report application where on the Private Sub Detail_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer) event, I have a simple rstTPPAvg.AddNew as shown below.

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rstTPPAvg As DAO.Recordset

'Get the database and Recordset
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rstTPPAvg = dbs.OpenRecordset("tbl_TPP_Avg")



rstTPPAvg.AddNew
rstTPPAvg("Track").Value = Me.Track
rstTPPAvg("DateToday").Value = Me.DateToday
rstTPPAvg("RaceNo").Value = Me.RaceNo
rstTPPAvg("PostPos").Value = [PostPos]
rstTPPAvg("Program PP").Value = [Program PP]
rstTPPAvg("HorseName").Value = HorseName
rstTPPAvg.Update
```

When I switch to PrintPreview only the records from the first page get saved.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.  Thank You.

Comment: You'll have to navigate to the last page in print preview to run Detail_Print() for all records. BTW, that's a very strange thing to do, I'm sure there is a better solution.

Comment: Yes I have come to that conclusion and am working on a "better way" but I thank you very much for your prompt reply.  It has been MANY years since I have programmed and am slowly get the hang of it again.